# Browser sometime can't open after reset

Tags: google-chrome, midori

Trying to open a browser, I get

```
(midori4:1990): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of/home/mr2uang/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Or I have this from Google Chrome

```
error while loading shared libraries: unexpected reloc type 0x01000001
```

Or

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Or

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:492:elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion((reloc->r_info) & 0xffffffff) == 8' failed!
```

Can you explain why I have these issues from both Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) and Midori? I need to reset a lot of times to use it normally. This happened after installed `ibus-unikey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a similar (may be exact) bug here [ibus/+bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1125944).

Removing the `/home/[user]/.config/ibus/bus` solve the problem.

If still not solved, remove the `ibus-unikey`

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus-unikey
```

Also from comments you used `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-vn/ppa` so you may get errors while running `apt-get update` So remove it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-vn/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

You can install `ibus-unikey` by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey
```

Comment: Yes i read it too, But after reset the other issue comes up or open normal...

Comment: can you provide link for `ibus-unikey` and also Are you getting all the mentioned errors? Then please remove `Or` =)

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove ibus-unikey` remove it and verify , whether you are getting errors or not--

Comment: Yes , i updated my name and this is `ibus-unikey` link `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-vn/ppa`  `sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey` sr i 'm newbie

Comment: After remove `ibus-unikey` and restart my google-chrome is working fine and Midori too

Comment: have you verified before , or just now?

Comment: i did remove `ibus-unikey` when i getting error `segmentation fault`

Comment: so your errors gone?...now what?..do you want ibus-unikey or can I post it as answer =)

Comment: I want ibus-unikey for vietnamese and browsers . :)

Comment: ok, if you available for few minutes here I will try to solve ?

Comment: ya sure , i believe u can help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30771/discussion-between-ravan-and-begood).